# Split comma delimited cell into multiple rows, keeping Original Rows as it is?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, spreadsheet

I have tried Excel Power Query option to Split Comma Seprated Values into Rows. It working Well.
But **I want to Keep original row as it is**.

Because Power Query Deletes Original Row and Generates New. I want to keep original row & Generate new rows below that. by comma delimiter.
**How can we do this?**

**Expectation:**

```
I have Data Rows like
1 - name - A,B
2 - name - A,B

It should Convert Like This.
1 - name - A,B
1 - name - A
1 - name - B
2 - name - A,B
2 - name - A
2 - name - B
```

Comment: Make a duplucate of the original and then split that one.

Comment: Create a table of original and load that and split it in a different sheet? Or copy the column in power query, split that new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the Simple solution.

1. Just Split All Rows by Comma Delimiter 'using power query'. we get "`After Split Rows`"
2. Then Paste All Original Rows Above "`After Split Rows`"
3. Add the filter to numbers/id row & use "`Sort smallest to largest`"
   and Done.

We get the Expected Result with the Original Rows & Split Rows Below them, as shown in above question.

Comment: You should not be referring to or using paste operations. Power query is meant to produce repeatable operations, without manual intervention. Paste is a specific manual action.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a custom column which contains a List consisting of Column 3 plus the Split of column 3 with the comma delimiter.
Then expand that column into rows

- Custom Column:
    `{[Column3]} & Text.Split([Column3],",")`

[image]

***original data***
[image]

**M Code**

```
let

//change Table name in next line to whatever your real source is named
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
                            {"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}}),

//create the list for the column    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {[Column3]} & Text.Split([Column3],",")),
    
//remove old column 3 and expand the list
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column3"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom")
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

***Results***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 imports.

What Power Query passes across to Excel is the model, and this can contain more than one table or process.

Import your data to be split. Carry out your `Split by Delimiter into Rows`. This will give you a table which has your separated values - `Table After Split`.

Import your data again as `Table Original`.

Append `Table After Split` to `Table After Split` to produce `Table Combined`.

Drop `Table Original` and `Table After Split` as they are no longer needed and are wasting memory.

Now what you have remaining in your model is your combined table.

Comment: not getting exact steps after "after Split"
I've tried to append but it just pasting original rows over Splited rows.
I've edited question, to show expectation.

Comment: What do you mean "not getting exact steps"? Do you mean you don't understand the process?